# ¿Por qué me devuelve un array vacío después de un foreach con JS y Mongodb?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Tengo este código pero no entiendo por qué me aparece un `array` vacío después de ejecutado el `foreach`:

```
const series = []

serriesGroup.forEach( async element => {
    const serie = await Serie.findById(element)
    //console.log(serie)
    series.push(serie)
})

console.log(series)
```

Alguien podría explicarme ¿por qué esto no funciona?.

Esperaría en vez de un `array` vacío algo como lo siguiente:

```
[
  {obj},
  {obj},
  {obj}
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes tener en cuenta lo que realiza tu código, te lo intentaré explicar paso por paso para que comprendas dónde está el error:

```
async [función]
```

La declaración [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona) creará una función asíncrona, lo que realizará será devolver un objeto [AsyncFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Funcionesas%C3%ADncronas) que funciona similar a una [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise), este será usado para resolverse devolviendo el valor de la función, y en caso de que la función genere algún error entonces se rechazará.

```
await [expresión]
```

El operador [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/await) solo debe usarse dentro de una función `async`, y lo que hará será esperar porque una `Promise` se resuelva o se rechace para continuar con la ejecución del código (es decir, es como situar una pausa dentro de la función `async`).

Pero debes tener en cuenta que `await` esperará por el resultado de la `Promise` y pausará solo la función `async`, pero el resto del código que esté fuera de la función `async` no se verá afectado, por lo tanto, continuará su ejecución. Siguiendo tu mismo patrón de código intentaré ponerte un ejemplo para que observes el orden de ejecución (fíjate en la hora de ejecución que saldrá a la derecha de cada `console.log`):

```js
const array = [];
const grupos = [10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000];

// La función cuadrado devolverá una promesa
// que será resuelta dos segundos después de ser llamada
const cuadrado = (numero) => new Promise((resolver) => {
  const resultado = Math.pow(numero, 2);
  setTimeout(() => resolver(resultado), 2000);
});

// Iterar en el array grupos
console.log('comenzando a iterar el array');
grupos.forEach( async (numero) => {
  const resultado = await cuadrado(numero);
  array.push(resultado);
  // Como este console log está dentro de una función async
  // y el operador await está esperando por el resultado
  // este console.log solo será ejecutado una vez que la promesa se resuelva
  console.log(resultado);
});

// este console.log no esperará por el await
// ni por la promesa devuelta por async
// este código será llamado una vez el forEach se ejecute
// por lo tanto en ese momento el array no tendrá valores todavía
// los valores se generarán uno por uno después de dos segundos
console.log(array);
```

Lee con detenimiento los comentarios que te he dejado en el código, como puedes ver, el `console.log` que tienes al final del `forEach` es llamado al inicio de la ejecución, en ese momento ninguna de las promesas se ha resuelto, y por lo tanto el `array` no tiene valores.

Si quieres ejecutar un código exactamente cuando todas las promesas se resuelvan, puedes situar una condición dentro del `forEach`, chequeando que se hayan ejecutado tantos números de promesas como índices tiene el array y solo intentar imprimir el `array` cuando estés seguro que todas las promesas se han resuelto, observa el siguiente snippet (y espera dos segundos para ver el resultado):

```js
const array = [];
const grupos = [10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000];
let resueltas = 0;

const cuadrado = (numero) => new Promise((resolver) => {
  const resultado = Math.pow(numero, 2);
  setTimeout(() => resolver(resultado), 2000);
});

console.log('comenzando a iterar el array');
grupos.forEach( async (numero) => {
  const resultado = await cuadrado(numero);
  array.push(resultado);
  // imprimir el array usando console.log
  // cuando la variable resueltas alcance la longitud del array
  // lo que significará que todas las promesas se han resuelto
  // debes esperar dos segundos para ver este console.log
  resueltas++;
  if (resueltas === grupos.length) {
      console.log(array);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo que ocurre es que el método `forEach` no espera que finalice el `callback` asíncrono antes de continuar con el siguiente. Por lo tanto el `async await` no te servirá ahí, sin embargo puedes utilizar otras formas para hacer lo que necesitas:

**Usar Promise.all**:

Devolverá los valores cuando todas las promesas terminen.

```
let seriesList = []

serriesGroup.forEach(element => {
    seriesList.push(Serie.findById(element))
})
const series = await Promise.all(seriesList)
console.log(series)
```

**Reemplazar tu forEach por un for**

```
const series = []
for (let i = 0; i < seriesGroup.length; i++) {
   const serie = await Serie.findById(serriesGroup[i])
   series.push(serie)
}
console.log(series)
```

Por último si lo que necesitas solamente es obtener los registros de una tabla por su id no necesitas iterar por cada uno de ellos, estarías generando muchas consultas en la base de datos(si tienes 1000 elementos en tu `seriesGroup` hara 1000 consultas a tu base de datos). Por tanto lo mas optimo es hacer un `$in` de esta manera:

```
const series = await Serie.find({
    _id: {
        $in: seriesGroup
    }
})
console.log(series)
```

Cabe destacar para que funcione el `await` para resolver las promesas debe estar en una función con su `async` correspondiente. De otra manera solo debes utilizar el método `then` para la promesa.

Comment: Ese `await Promise.all` no va a funcionar si no es dentro de una función `async`.  El `forEach` y el `for` funcionarían de la misma manera. Además, para que funcione ese `await` dentro del `for` tienes que poner también todo dentro de una función `async`.

Answer (score 1):

La forma mas habitual de resolver un array de llamadas asincronas sería usando `Promise.all()`, esta forma acepta un array de promesas, por lo que `.map()` sería mas adecuado y hay al menos 2 posibilidades de obtener el valor, usando `.then()` o `await`, En este último caso, el `await` **siempre** debe estar dentro de un `async`. Aquí te dejo los dos ejemplos:

```js
let seriesList = [1, 2, 3].map(element =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        setTimeout(() => resolve(element+1), 250)// < -- Solo como ejemplo asíncrono
    )
);

Promise.all(seriesList).then(r=>console.log(r));
```

```js
let seriesList = [1, 2, 3].map(element =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        setTimeout(() => resolve(element+1), 250)// < -- Solo como ejemplo asíncrono
    )
);

(async ()=> {
   const resultado = await Promise.all(seriesList); 
   console.log(resultado)
})();
```